# Error "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." in MatLab using importdata with a text file

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I'm trying to import data using importdata and when I try to parse the returned data to create a matrix I get, "Index exceeds matrix dimensions".  Below is my code...

```
traindata = importdata('textfile.txt');
%[A,delimiterOut,headerlinesOut] = importdata('textfile.txts');
disp(traindata); %everytime I run this code traindata increments by 1

X = traindata('   ',1:8); %this is where the error occurs, delimiter is 3 spaces
Y = traindata('   ',9);
```

Below is the format of the data in textfile.txt...

,,,5.4,,,0.0,,,0.0,,,1.6,,,2.5,,,1.0,,,6.7,,,2.8,,,6.1
,,,4.2,,,1.1,,,3.6,,,3.9,,,1.8,,,9.3,,,3.3,,,2.4,,,7.6

The data is delimited by spaces (I used commas to try and show the spaces between the data) and a newline at the end of each line.  I've open textfile.txt in word and verified by viewing the hidden formatting characters.  I've tried the code...

```
[A,delimiterOut,headerlinesOut] = importdata(inputfile);
```

to try to verify the delimiter used and I get the error, "Too many output arguments."  As you can see I'm trying to create two matrices (X,Y) from the imported data.  I've seen this specific error on stackoverflow but nothing regarding importdata.  I've also tried dlmread and have not had luck.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Tried the suggestion of importing the data using file->import data but I receive the error..
Error using importdata
Too many output arguments.

"Error in uiimport/runImportdata (line 433)
                        [datastruct, OTextDelimiter, OHeaderLines] = ...

Error in uiimport/gatherFilePreviewData (line 376)
        [datastruct, textDelimiter, headerLines]= runImportdata(fileAbsolutePath, type);

Error in uiimport (line 194)
[ctorPreviewText, ctorHeaderLines, ctorDelim] = ..."

I'm starting to wondering if it's some sort of application bug.  Here are some specifics..
"R2012a (7.0.14.739) 64 bit (Win64)".  The encoding of the text file is utf-8.  Thanks again for the help!

Looks like the array returned from importdata is a 1 element array.

```
train = importdata('textfile.txt');
fprintf('1st element in array %d\n', traindata(1)); % prints a number a number that increase     each time I run this function ie 1,2,3,4...
fprintf('2nd element in array %d\n', traindata(2)); % produces error, "Index exceeds matrix dimensions"
```

Answer (score 0):

I often find it useful to use matlab's built in GUI for importing a data file, which can help to visualised how the data will be imported.  There is an option in here to produce the code required to replicate the options that were selected during the import which will allow you to work out how to dynamically import the data.

Just go to:

File >>> Import Data...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I get an error when I try file -> import data.